# Using JQuery to change CSS value of all divs with same class but only if a contained checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm new to this world and finding myself on a very steep learning curve.
I've managed to sort all issues so far by looking through this site but this one has me stumped! I've given it a full day and can't progress so i'm hoping someone can help.

I've 2 roles, student and assessor.

Student completes their work and then the assessor marks it and a checkbox is ticked if the answer is sufficient.

Student then looks at their work and should see a green background to the answer with the checked checkbox, no background to those with unchecked.

At the moment my code is changing the background colour of all divs with the same class regardless of if the checkbox is checked or not.

Any help as to where i'm going wrong would be very much appreciated.

A sample question within a HTML form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.answer').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input.cb:checked').prop('checked')) {

      $('.answer').css("background-color", "#a5de76");

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-left">1. Describe the procedures in place when a steward supervises spectator entry.</div>
<p></p>
<div class="answer"><textarea id="U1Q1" name="U1Q1" rows="5" cols="70"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['U1Q1'])?></textarea>
  <?php echo '<input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="n" class="hidden" value="v"' . ($row['U1Q1R']==1 ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . '>';?>
  <input style="color:blue" id="textfield" name="U1Q1F" class="textfields" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['U1Q1F'])?>" readonly />
</div>
```

This is how it currently looks on screen (the checkboxes will be hidden once I have the code working:

[student page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSKos.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the current context `this` and change:

```
$('.answer').css("background-color", "#a5de76");
```

to

```
$(this).css("background-color", "#a5de76");
```

So, that only current checked answer background color is changed.

**Full Code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.answer').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input.cb').prop('checked')) {
      $(this).css("background-color", "#a5de76");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-left">1. Describe the procedures in place when a steward supervises spectator entry.</div>
<p></p>
<div class="answer">
  <textarea id="U1Q1" name="U1Q1" rows="2" cols="70"></textarea>
  <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="n" class="hidden" value="v" checked>
  <input style="color:blue" id="textfield" name="U1Q1F" class="textfields" type="text" value="" readonly />
</div>
<div class="answer">
  <textarea id="U1Q1" name="U1Q1" rows="2" cols="70"></textarea>
  <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="n" class="hidden" value="v">
  <input style="color:blue" id="textfield" name="U1Q1F" class="textfields" type="text" value="" readonly />
</div>
<div class="answer">
  <textarea id="U1Q1" name="U1Q1" rows="2" cols="70"></textarea>
  <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="n" class="hidden" value="v" checked>
  <input style="color:blue" id="textfield" name="U1Q1F" class="textfields" type="text" value="" readonly />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer the question. I was so close!! I had tried $(this) before but I've had so many different combinations of code that I mustn't have put it together with this version.